# How to force the border color of a cell in a html table

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is really simple. How can I force one cell's border style to override the other values around it?

The problem is shown in the image below. I want to force the border of the 'Today' cell to be completely black on all sides, rather than just the bottom and the right:

[image]

Here is the example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q22ycLrx/2/)

css code:

```
 td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.event {
  border: 2px solid gray !important;
}

.today {
  border: 2px solid black !important;
}
```

Table html:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td class="today">Today</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem here is the usage of the border-collapse: collapse; style. To solve that you could try one of the following solutions:

**Solution 1:**

You could try adding a different border style:

```
.today {
  border: 2px double black!important;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h1t0ctmx/

Here is a documentation about the border conflict resolution:

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively you could just add the following to your surrounding table:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ggckr5mL/

Here is a documentation about the border-collapse property and some examples which explain the behaviour:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: Thanks, but that changes the borders of all the other cells - I just want to force the border on one cell.

Comment: Hi I updated the answer. I suppose you don't have much option here. What I also tried was to use outline: 2px solid black!important.

Comment: I updated the answer...solution 2 might what you are looking for.

Comment: I think that I've found a solution. According to the [border conflict resolution rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution), if I increase the border width of the style I want to be dominant, then it will take precedence.

Comment: Just see the solution 2 fiddle which seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Just seen your solution 2 - yup that is perfect! Thanks.

Comment: The conflict resolution seems to match the solution. I add it to the answer for others. Nice find thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of the css and html with border-collapse as a fix. Hope it helps

```css
 table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.event {
  border: 2px solid gray !important;
}

.today {
  border: 2px solid black !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td class="today">Today</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td class="event">Event</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
    <td>Detail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As d.h. points out, the main problem is `border-collapse: collapsed`. If you need to keep that, one tactic I've found to work is to use contrasting inset/outset values for the border-style of the cells.

```
td {
  border: 1px outset gray;
}

td.selected {
  border: 1px inset blue;
}
```

Give me the following result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you can use jquery than may be this would help.
Add jquery..

```
// Add Jquery
$('td:contains("Today")').addClass('today');

//Add css

.today {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cacawak/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: He is not asking about how to add a css class. He is asking about the fact that the border only appears on the bottom and the right.

Comment: Thanks. Noted. My Bad

Answer (score -1):

An even better solution is to be more specific in the CSS you are using. It's not always the neat way to use !important, although it's not wrong. In more complex applications, it can cause problems. If you want to overrule this styling another time, you can only do this by being a bit sloppy (using atleast another !important).

Specific css is stronger than the less specific css.
For instance ".table .today" will overrule ".today".

```
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.table .event {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.table .today {
 border: 2px double black;
}
```

Seen an example: https://jsfiddle.net/crix/fuy687nb/

Take a look at: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: The question is not about the !important attribute and your css line isn't even working for his case!

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/0bhyq3f7/ It is not working without the !important attribute

Comment: That is cause you didnt used the exact same styling :). 
Try to take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/crix/fuy687nb/

Comment: There is a spacing in your table which is not what op's example looks like. Try it with border-collapse: collapse and see what happens.

Comment: You are right, there was no bootstrap included. I added bootstrap to have an better example.

Comment: It is not about bootstrap but rather about the border-collapse attribute. Bootstrap sets the border-collapse: collapse; style.